# How to set value of a Date Textfield in Material UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, material-ui

I've got an array of objects, where each object contains an id and a date value. For example, my array, call it `stepDates`, could look something like this:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    date: "2021-07-23"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    date: null
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    date: null
  }
]
```

I also have another array of objects, where there is more information on the objects that you see above. This array looks something like:

```
const steps = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: start
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: middle
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: end
  }
]
```

I'm trying to iterate over each of the objects in the above array to display the date using `TextField` with Material UI (without the user having to select the date themselves). However, I am getting an error when setting the `value` prop for the `TextField` component. For now, I have this:

```
{steps.map((step, index) => {
  return (
    <TextField
      id={step.id}
      label={step.name}
      type={"date"}
      onChange={event => handleStepDateChange(event.target.value, step.name)}
      value={
        stepDates.map(stepDate => {
          if (stepDate.id === step.id) return stepDate.date
        })
      }
    />
  )
})}
```

Give the above, I am trying to either display the date from the `stepDates` for each object if it exists, otherwise, if it's null, I just want to display the date field unselected, such as "dd/mm/yyyy".

However, in doing the above, I am getting two different errors. The first error where the date field exists gives me the following:

> The specified value "2021-07-23,,,,,,,,,,,,," does not conform to the
> required format, "yyyy-MM-dd"

And the second error where the date is null, gives me this error (twice for each date that is null as above):

> The specified value ",,,,,,,,,,,,," does not conform to the
> required format, "yyyy-MM-dd"

Comment: You're using `map` but I think you mean to use `filter`? With `map` the value will be an array with all `undefined`, if the value couldn't be found, or with some values set to the date and all others undefined, like you showed, if there's a match. Try`filter` instead (for the `value` prop I mean).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I had originally used `filter` but was trying something else. With `filter`, I'm getting an error `The specified value "[object Object]" does not conform to the required format, "yyyy-MM-dd"`. There is only one occurrence of this error though and I'm not really sure where it's happening.

Comment: Yes because you get the entire object back from the filtering, you need to take the date out from it after you have checked if it was found or not.. actually, `find` is a better alternative here. Like `stepObjects.find(stepDate => stepDate.id === step.id)?.date || "dd/mm/yyyy"`. Then you get the date if the object is found, otherwise `dd/mm/yyyy`.

Comment: Filter also returns an array so it still requires some post-processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're going to want to use `find` instead of `map`. so you value attribute will look like so:

```
value={stepDates.find(stepDate => stepDate.id === step.id).date}
```

Comment: yeah, sorry about that. thanks for noticing!

Comment: Thank you! I will give that a try.

Comment: Glad to hear! Good luck!